# Want a .bat file to run during a certain time range

Tags: batch-file, time, scheduled-tasks

I want to have my .bat file from 9:00 am to 6:00 am the next day. This is my code shown below:

```
powershell -window minimized -command ""
@echo off

 cls
:start 
cscript DisplayBoard.vbs "FilePath\macro.xlsm"
goto start
I tried adding the set hours one and the time code but neither one worked with my code. Can someone help?
```

Update this is the code i tried

```
powershell -window minimized -command ""
@echo off
SET hour=%time:~0,2%

SET shouldrun=True
IF %hour% geq 9 SET shouldrun=False
IF %hour% leq 6 SET shouldrun=False

IF "%shouldrun%"=="True" (
    CALL cls
:start 
cscript DisplayBoard.vbs "S:\FilePath\macro.xlsm"
goto start
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Best (and easiest) solution would utilize Windows Task Scheduler to run the job on a specified schedule. Triggers, schedule, etc. can be defined within the task configuration.

Comment: Hello @Cheese that works great for starting it, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to end it at a specific time.

Comment: Within the trigger, select the "Stop task if it runs longer than:" checkbox and set the time so that it stops at your specified time (9 hours).